# Simple solution to use html form as input for python script

Tags: javascript, html, python-2.7

I have looked everywhere and I didn't found really good answer.
I am generating local html page with python and I want to read data from form over there, use this as input for python script and display return from there properly.

```
f = open('testapi.html','w')

message = """
<html>

<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"/>
<script>

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p>Search for best deals</p>
        <form name="deals" action="">
        <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr> <th>Title </th> <th><input type="text" id="Title" value=""><br></th> </tr>
            <tr> <th>Lowest price</th> <th><input type="text" id="LowerPrice" value=""><br></th> </tr>
            <tr> <th>Highest price</th> <th><input type="text" id="UpperPrice" value=""><br></th> </tr>
            <tr> <th>Sale only</th> <th><input type="checkbox" id="OnSale" value=""></br></th> </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <p>Sort by:</p>
            <input type="radio" name="sort" id="DealRating" value="a">Deal rating<br>
            <input type="radio" name="sort" id="Title" value="b">Title<br>
            <input type="radio" name="sort" id="Price" value="c">Price<br>
            <input type="radio" name="sort" id="Release" value="d">Release<br>

        <input type="button" name="Sumbit" value="Submit" onClick="">
        </form>
        <p> Note: all fields are optional, fill only what you are intrested in.</p>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <p> OR </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p>Search for your favourite games<p>
        <form name="games" action="">
        <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr><th>Title</th> <th><input type="text" id="GameTitle" value=""></br></th></tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="button" name="Sumbit" value="Submit" onClick="">
        </form>
        <p> Note: all fields are optional, fill only what you are intrested in.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
"""

f.write(message)
f.close()
```

my question now is: how I can use that form input to process it in api search and then return result back on this page?
OR
eventually: how to runnpython script from my page and just display results?

Note: I have to use python for this. This is requirement for my project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for something like a CGI script in python. Python has some support for this in the standard library.

There are a [lot of tutorials](https://wiki.python.org/moin/CgiScripts) that explain that in detail how to do that exactly.

You could also use [mod_python](http://modpython.org/), which is an extension for the Apache web server to run and parse python scripts.

Comment: I would like to avoid CGI, because it requires server. I would like to run it locally without even setting up a server.

Comment: @Trykon Then I don't understand what you want to do. Who should fill out this form? Why? If all you want to do is send data to an API, then just do that without the overhead of HTML.

Comment: This HTML is there to work as GUI as I am beginner with python and gui in python for now is out of my reach